# Nesting DataFrame needed for validating data with Pandera DataFrameModel

Tags: pandas, database, numpy, pandera

I have a DataFrame schema that I have created using Pandera's DataFrame model called 'params'. This DataFrame is basically DataFrame of floats, for which I need to do some validation on before it is used my application.

I have another DataFrame, let's call it `params2` for which the one of the validation checks being run on `params` needs access to.

I can not store `params2` in the columns of `params`. How can I pass this DataFrame along to the validation checks being run on `params`?

So far I tried creating a custom class called SecretDF that inherits from pandas DataFrame, and creates an empty DataFrame hidden inside the class. I added additional methods that would allow accessing that DataFrame, but the Pandera checks can't see that this method is defined on the DataFrame.

Below is a minimal reproducible example of the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandera as pa

# Example dataframes
params = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
})

params2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'reference_value': [0.5, 2.5, 3.5]
})

# A custom class inheriting from pd.DataFrame to hold a secret dataframe
class SecretDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._secret_df = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_secret(self, df):
        self._secret_df = df

    def get_secret(self):
        return self._secret_df

# Using DataFrameModel to define schema
class ParamsSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    value: pa.Column[float] = pa.Field(gt=0, check_name=True, nullable=False)
    # Check function to validate values of params based on params2

    @pa.dataframe_check
    def validate_based_on_secret_df(pls, df: pd.DataFrame):
        if secret_df is None:
            return True
        return (df[‘value’] < df._secret_df["reference_value"]).all()
    

# Try to validate
params_with_secret = SecretDF(params)
params_with_secret.set_secret(params2)

try:
    pa_params = pd.DataFrame[ParamsSchema](
    params_with_secret
    )
    print("Validation passed")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Validation failed: {e}")
```

This does not work, as df won’t have the attribute `_secret_df` in the check `validate_based_on_secret_df`. For my specific application, having the check column be inside of `params` is NOT an option, this is a simplified example from my repo. Creating the functions and checks on the fly is not an option either, as the schema is hardcoded in a `.py` file. What can be done here?

Comment: You should build a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your issue, with synthetic data. Also, doing this solves a large proportion of issues beforehand, and it will make it clearer to people willing to help. Please try to edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Liris I have edited the post, is this good?

Comment: It's much better, but not good yet. I obtain `TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable` before getting to the error that matter. You should always run you example before pasting here.